# RemoteWebDriver SetFileDetector gives an exception org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file using webDriver in google chrome using RemoteWebDriver.
So I am using SetFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()) and then driver.findElement(By.id('abc')).sendKeys(value);

But I am getting an exception org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:.

Answer (score 3):

According to this issue page http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2653 this might happen if you use ChromeDriver(), not RemoteWebDriver().